# As per iOS design standards do all 1x, 2x, 3x has same font size?

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface, user-experience, iosdeployment

For example if any screen has 14pt of text for 1X, Does 2x & 3X screens also has same size of font? or they can be relevant same as android GUI standards.

Comment: They will be same in every device.

Comment: You should read https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/visual-design/typography/

Comment: @ClausJørgensen actually i'm designer so i know the standards size to put while designing. But I was not sure about how conversion work for each screen. So had confusion that just Android ios also change font size relevantly or they put same size in each resolution. Thanks btw.

Comment: @YashpalSindhav well, you don't seem to be aware of dynamic font sizes. The link details those as well.

Comment: @ClausJørgensen Thanks! Got your point. Actually as a UI designer I had query that if I have put some random text size as 14pt for designing in 2X(640x1136), Do that text should be of same size for 1X & 3X as per Apple GUI guidelines?

Comment: @YashpalSindhav Yes it is same for 1x,2x,3x. These kind of resolutions are used in assets ([check](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/icons-and-images/image-size-and-resolution/))  For UI design we use vary for traits or size classes ([Check](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Size-ClassSpecificLayout.html)).